# Hoe does $A\otimes C_m \cong A/mA$ yield $C_n \otimes C_m \cong C_{(n,m)}$?

Tags: tensor-products

How can I obtain $C_n \otimes C_m \cong C_{(n,m)}$ from $A\otimes C_m \cong A/mA$, where $A$ is an abelian group?

Comment: $C_n\otimes C_m\cong C_n/mC_n$. Now, observe that $mC_n=(m,n)C_n\subseteq C_n$, so $C_n\otimes C_m\cong C_n/(m,n)C_n\cong C_{(m,n)}$.

Comment: @KentaS Thank you very much for the comment.